# How do I return mat-file channel names using Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mat-file

I'm manipulating MATLAB mat-files using Python 2.x and have run into a problem I can't even Google my way out of.

I found it easy to access anything I wanted in the mat-file once I supply the channel name. As a trivial example, to print the fields of a channel I'd use:

```
for field in mat_file['sample_channel_name']._fieldnames:
    print field
```

The thing is, I don't want to be hardcoding the channel names and can't find out how to return them from the mat-file using SciPy.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `loadmat` returns the contents of a .mat file as a dictionary. You can access the names with `mat_file.keys()`

Comment: Ah, embarrassingly simple! Somehow I thought it was a list of dictionaries. Thank you.